# Kendo Grid JSON Not Consistant

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

I have json returning from an API that is not consistant, meaning some records have "age" associated with them while others do not.

I am trying to populate a Kendo UI Grid in order to display/manipulate the data. Unfortunately, when the records that do not have "Age" associated with them return with records that do, kendo breaks down with an error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Age is not defined**

Here is the example of the working grid: http://jsfiddle.net/tmort/CVkpF/

And here is the grid with one record returning without "Age": http://jsfiddle.net/tmort/CVkpF/1/ - You can see the error appear in the Console, not on the page itself.

Is there any way I can make the grid dynamic enough to understand that age hasn't returned, set it to null, and then continue on?

Code I'm using:

```
    var data = [
    {
    FirstName: 'John',
    LastName: 'Doe',
    City: 'New York City',
    Title: 'Supervisor',
    BirthDate: '1/1/1975',
    Age: '37',
    },
    {
    FirstName: 'Jane',
    LastName: 'Doe',
    City: 'Buffalo',
    Title: 'Sales Associate',
    BirthDate: '1/1/1980',

    }
    ]
$(document).ready(function() {
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: data,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            FirstName: { type: "string" },
                            LastName: { type: "string" },
                            City: { type: "string" },
                            Title: { type: "string" },
                            BirthDate: { type: "date" },
                            Age: { type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            height: 500,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name"
                },
                {
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "Last Name"
                },
                {
                    field: "City"
                },
                {
                    field: "Title"
                },
                {
                    field: "BirthDate",
                    title: "Birth Date",
                    template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'
                },
                {
                    field: "Age"
                }
            ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");

    });
```

​Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kendo grids do not support missing values. Your object must contain every member of each row to be able to bind it to a grid. Blank/null values should be just that - empty strings or null but they must exist in your JSON result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if kendo grids are that flexible, but what you could do is to process the datasource before you put it into the grid. You could add Age as a field in the datasource or set the grid depending on hte fields present. This might not work as well if you are performing CRUD operations on the source, but if its only a display of data this might work well for you.

Others might have better insight into the kendo framework, this is just a suggestion for a quick workaround!

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is a great fix, only issue I see is there will be MANY variable fields, so it will be impossible for me to predict and "hard code" all of them to fix the issue. Appreciate the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try and send the missing field (Age) as null. If you are getting data from the controller, you can add an extra field and send it to the UI. This would make things work in a proper way. Just my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

for you columns add a template with a data.field will work ie.

```
       ...
       columns: [
            {
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name",
                template: "#= data.FirstName != null ? FirstName : '' #"
            },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                template: "#= data.LastName != null ? LastName : '' #"
            },
            {
                field: "City",
                template: "#= data.City != null ? City : '' #"
            },
            {
                field: "Title",
                template: "#= data.Title != null ? Title : '' #"
            },
            {
                field: "BirthDate",
                title: "Birth Date",
                template: '#= data.BirthDate != null ? kendo.toString(BirthDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") : "" #'
            },
            {
                field: "Age",
                template: "#= data.Age != null ? Age : '' #"
            }
        ]
        ...
```